# Show / Hide Image in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, image, move

how to show or hide a image in Swift by taping on a Button?
For example:

i have ImageA and ImageB and one Button which i want to use to move ImageA to ImageB and back to ImageA and so on..

It works perfect to move from ImageA to ImageB, but how can i move back to ImageA?

My code is:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var Bild1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var Bild2: UIImageView!

@IBAction func pressedButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    Bild1.hidden = true
    Bild2.hidden = false
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Bild1.hidden = false
    Bild2.hidden = true

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Bild1.isHidden = false
    Bild2.isHidden = true
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func pressedButton(sender: AnyObject) 
{
    Bild1.isHidden = !Bild1.isHidden
    Bild2.isHidden = !Bild2.isHidden
}
```

Comment: @Jayesh Miruliya You should avoid use tags whenever it is possible

Comment: Updated to isHidden in Swift 4.

Answer (score 7):

```
@IBAction func pressedButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    Bild1.isHidden = !Bild1.isHidden
    Bild2.isHidden = !Bild2.isHidden
}
```

This will toggle the image property between show and hidden. 
Syntax is Swift4 compatible

Answer (score 0):

try replacing with:

```
@IBAction func pressedButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if Bild1.hidden {
        Bild1.hidden = false
        Bild2.hidden = true
    } else {
        Bild1.hidden = true
        Bild2.hidden = false
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func pressedButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    Bild1.hidden = !Bild1.hidden
    Bild2.hidden = !Bild2.hidden
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. do i need another change in the codes?

Comment: No you don't. All three solutions in this topic should work. Probably you have some mistakes in other part of code. Provide information about how and when you assigning images.

Comment: Could you explain how your answer addresses the problem(s) from the question? Code-only answers are not very useful, especially for further readers that stumble upon this post. Thanks!